# How to express displacement/height with respect to time for non-uniform newtonian gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, calculus

I have tried integrating $v dv = \frac{-G M}{x^{2}} dx$ to get the popular $v = \sqrt{2 G M \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{h} \right)}$.

After this, I used trigonometric substitutions to get time in terms of height. Since the equation obtained (written below) is transcendental, I can't express height as a function of time.

How do I express height as a function of time? Is there some other method of solving the differential equation or is the equation necessary entirely different?

The equation I am getting is $\sqrt{ \frac{h^3}{2 G M}} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin \left( \sqrt{\frac{x}{h} } \right) + \frac{1}{h} \sqrt{x \left( x - h \right) } \right) = t$

Comment: You don’t have to integrate anything to get your expression for $v$. It follows immediately from the conservation of energy.

Comment: You can’t get an analytic expression for $x(t)$… only for $t(x)$.

Comment: This question would be much clearer if you showed $t(x)$. Without it, readers won’t understand what trascendental equation you are talking about.

Comment: @Ghoster I have added the equation showing t(x). Could you suggest some new method or new equation? Thanks

Comment: You can’t get a nice formula for $x(t)$. You can get an ugly [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field). Why is $t(x)$ not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, I propose the following solution:

Applying Newton's Law:
$$m\frac{d^2h}{dt^2}=-\frac{GMm}{(R+h)^2}$$
Where $R$=Radious of the earth

Solving the above differential equation, you get,

[image: 1]

[Follow this link for a detailed solution of the above differential equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=h%27%27%28t%29%20%3D%20-GM%2F%28R%2Bh%28t%29%29%5E2)

Where $C_1$ and $C_2$ can be obtained by applying 2 boundary conditions such as the following (it may vary as the case may be):

1. At $t=0, h=0$
2. At $t=0$, initial speed is known i.e. $\frac{dh}{dt}=u$

Comment: I tried to view the detailed solution but couldn't do it. How was the differential equation solved? I tried to obtain a similar equation but couldn't do it. Thanks

Comment: You need to have pro account in order to view full steps.